# Updating table in php-mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i am writing a php code involving mysql. At one point, i have to update a table in my database for which i am using the below 2 statements. But these are not working.

```
$temp = $row['tracking_id'];  

mysql_query("UPDATE order_products SET state=4.00 WHERE tracking_id = '$temp'");
```

Note that i don't get an error message. The table is not updated though. Also note, the column names, table names are correct. I have also tried without the single '' quotes around $temp in WHERE clause.

The connection to database is fine. I know this cos select queries are working fine.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Have you ever thought about putting '' around 4.00?

Comment: did you echo mysql_error(); ? is temp contains the correct value? did you try add '' around 4.00 ?

Comment: Try this `echo "UPDATE order_products SET state=4.00 WHERE tracking_id = '$temp'"` and paste the answer in mysql command line client. Should give you details of what you are missing

Comment: Yes i tried quotes around 4.00 too, didnt work

Comment: @Nibhrit: Please post the mysql_error(); you got

Comment: SOLVED::::It was a common server error. Sorry. And Thanks :)

Comment: it was common **programming** error. Ignoring server errors is entirely programmer's fault.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to var_dump temp

```
var_dump($temp);
```

and also check errors from your query

```
mysql_query("UPDATE order_products SET state=4.00 WHERE tracking_id = '$temp'") or trigger_error(mysql_error()." <here is that problem");
```

It will give you your answer

Comment: Yeah that worked. Looks like someone deleted the table i am working on. The database is on a common server so it took a while to figure that out. mysql_error was great help. thanks

Comment: Please, don't die! That's both insecure and unusable.

Comment: @Pekka: Ah I'm blind. It definitelly isn't insecure, but unsuable, yes. Thanks for suggestion

Comment: @genesis the "insecure" bit refers to the fact that the error message is displayed even in production mode, while the assumption is that `trigger_error()` will not.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly check what is the value in $temp.

If value is fine the do it like this to echo your query.

echo    $sql = "UPDATE order_products SET state=4.00 WHERE tracking_id = '$temp'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

its only for testing and check the query is it fine? try running it directly and see if any error comes

Answer (score 0):

How did you fetch the row?

using `mysql_tetch_row` or `mysql_fetch_array`?

if you used `fetch_array` it's not an associative array and you can't do `row['something']`, only `row[index]`, so use `fetch_row` instead.

print the value of temp to verify it's ok and if still can't find the problem try using the `mysql_error()` function to prinT the last mysql error.

Comment: the row fetch is working fine cos im echo-ing the contents of the row above this statement

Answer (score 0):

> Note that i don't get an error message.

No wonder. You have to ask a database for the error message.

```
$tmp = mysql_real_escape_string($row['tracking_id']);  
$sql = "UPDATE order_products SET state=4.00 WHERE tracking_id = '$tmp'";
mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." ".$sql);
var_dump(mysql_affected_rows); //to see if rows were changed.
```

if it prints only 0 - then you have a row with exactly same values in your table already